# Problem at redeployement on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am developing a Next application in TS. It's really small and does not require complicated packages or librairies.
However, I stubbled upon a weird issue that I do not comprehend: when I am creating a new eb environment, I choose the "upload local file" option to deploy my application. This works without any issue. But when I try to upload the next source file (the next version of the app), my environment crashes.

Without panicking - yet - I pulled up the logs from the instance and parsed through them. I found that a problem that occurs in the eb-engine.log, when the following command is run:
`Running command /bin/su webapp -c npm --omit=dev install`

I get an error called ENOMEM, which after some research online seems to be a problem of memory on the instance.
A bit strange for a small app, but I was managing to keep on coding by downing and creating a new environment every time (as a reminder, the first deployment is always successful).

This got a bit problematic to fine tune some stuff that required to constantly create a whole new environment, so I dove deeper and found another solution:

- to create an .ebextensions directory in my project's root
- to create a .config file inside this directory
- to enter the following config inside the file

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: RootVolumeSize
    value: "250"
```

My understanding of this idea being that changing the size should help with the deployment.

And it did! The redeployement is possible... once. Meaning if I already uploaded my app for the first time (at environment creation), I can put these options and the second version of the app will be correctly deployed. But any following deployments will fail again.

Next thing I tried was to change the "value" for these options settings. If I only change the value by 1, the deployment does not work. However, if it is of higher value (5+), wether up or down, the deployment will work correctly.

To me it seems like scaling the instance size up or down will create a new instance, which allows for a correct deployment.

But why? I don't understand why eb reacts like that. And while changing this value in the .config file is easier than deleting/creating environments, this is still a dodgy "fix".

If anyone can explain this behaviour, I would be really grateful. I am also able to provide more informations regarding the issue.